# St Michael's cave in Gibraltar

Tags: geospatial, research

[St Michael's cave in Gibraltar](https://www.google.com/search?q=st%20michael%27s%20cave%20gibraltar&client=ms-android-samsung-ss&prmd=minv&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRyvnXm-b2AhUV4XMBHZ1fBPgQ_AUoAnoECAIQAg)

[Unesco World Heritage site](https://www.google.com/search?q=unesco%20world%20heritage%20site&client=ms-android-samsung-ss&prmd=nbiv&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiy_LDqm-b2AhXVW3wKHd6ABrIQ_AUoA3oECAIQAw&biw=360&bih=674&dpr=2)

I would like to know how a new world heritage site is updated in the Unesco world heritage sites repository?

Can the St.Michael's Cave in Gibraltar be added as a new Unesco world heritage site?

Comment: Are you talking about the actual selection process of locations to become part of the UNESCO World Heritage Site, or something else? If the former, this article details the exact selection process: https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/expeditions/the-unesco-world-heritage-site-selection-process/#:~:text=As%20stated%20before%2C%20in%20order,%E2%80%9D%20(Operational%20Guidelines%202012).

Comment: Yes. Actual selection process of locations to become part of the UNESCO World Heritage Site. Thanks.